# Unable to perform string operations on the list elements

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, append

I have a list,

```
list1 = [<td>-267</td>, <td>1,420</td>, <td>1,997</td>, <td>1,241</td>]
```

From the items inside I want to remove `<td>` and `</td>` , so I did this:

```
# Created empty list:
final = []

# then,
for i in list1:
    i.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '')
    final.append(i)
```

Gives error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable while appending to empty list.

It works fine here:

```
a = '<td>-267</td>'
a.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '')
```

output = '-267'

Why doesn't it work with the append method guys?

Comment: You're missing the assignment statement, ``i = i.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '')`` then append or just ``final.append(i.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', ''))``

Comment: This looks like XY problem. How did you get the list populated in the first place? It looks like you try to parse html source, so use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing to almost right , just that you missed assigning value to i

```
Created empty list:
final = []
then,
for i in list1:
    i=i.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '')
    final.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['<td>-267</td>', '<td>1,420</td>', '<td>1,997</td>', '<td>1,241</td>']
final = []

for i in list1:
    i = i.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '')
    final.append(i)
print(final)
```

First of all your list should be of string values, and try the above code

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign it back to variable 'i', after you replace <td> and </td>:

```
final1 = []
for i in ["<td>-267</td>", "<td>1,420</td>", "<td>1,997</td>", "<td>1,241</td>"]:
    i = i.replace("<td>", "").replace("</td>", "")
    final1.append(i)
print(final1)
```

Output: ['-267', '1,420', '1,997', '1,241']

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the value back to the `i`. *Strings* are immutable data types so the `replace` method **returns** a copy of the string where all occurrences of a substring are replaced with another substring.

```py
list1 = ["<td>-267</td>", " <td>1,420</td>", " <td>1,997</td>", " <td>1,241</td>"]

final = []
for i in list1:
    i = i.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '')
    final.append(i)
print(final)
```